# How to access the previous sibling through an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, frontend

At the moment, I'm using ELEMENTREF to access the DOM through the Redenrer2. Here's a basic example:

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'yellow');
  }

}
```

The above code was just a test to leave the syntax highlight with the yellow color.

However, I need to know how do I access the previous element and capture the width of it to move to a left-style property?

Ex: Former brother has the width of 400px. The current element has the left of 400px.

I'm counting on the collaboration.

Comment: You can't, you need a parent directive to manage the children or use a shared service to trigger the other directive from the sibling.

Comment: In Renderer2, I have the abstract nextSibling (node: any): any. Would it have something similar to grab the previousSibling, for example?

Comment: If understand right you have something like a list and you want each next element (brother) to have `left` property equall to the width of the "elder-brother" (previous sibiling)?

Comment: That's it @Християн Христов! You need that, but you have to fight with this scenario.

Comment: You can try passing as an input the elder-brother to the next in the line, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the parent element:

`let parent = this.renderer.parentNode(this.elementRef.nativeElement);`

and then select his child somehow, maybe give them incrementing ID's:

`let sibling = parent.querySelector('#child5');`

and then you have siblings width:

`let width = sibling.offsetWidth;`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are generating this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null; at new HighlightDirective (highlight.directive.ts:10); at createClass (core.js:9303)

Comment: Now, how to select all the children from the parent ... if I can do this, I can solve my problem.